# Fetching from an associative table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need create SQL query, which retrieve articles, which have given tags. Relation is M:N, so one article can has associated N tags.

```
id_article        id_tag             article_has_tag
1                 1, SQL             1, 1
2                 2, HTML            1, 4
3                 3, PHP             2, 1
                  4, JAVA            2, 2
                                     3, 4
                                     3, 1
```

For example, if are selected SQL **AND** Java, result should be id_article: **1** and **3**. not (1,2,3)

```
SELECT * FROM article_has_tag a 
where a.id_tag = 1 and a.id_tag = 4
-- returns zero rows
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32e2a/4)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM article_has_tag a 
where a.id_tag = 1 OR a.id_tag = 4
group by id_article
having count(*)=2
```

Comment: There is only limitation on count of tags. If you remove this condition, you will get article ID 2 too. I need only articles which have SQL and JAVA, e.g.

Comment: @PeterJurkovič HAVING sum(if(a.id_tag = 1 OR a.id_tag = 4,1,0))=2

Comment: Probable you don't understand the question. Article can has N tags, condition can has N tags.

Comment: I would say you don't understand the answer. Suppose you pass list of tag ids e.g. (1,5,7,9) so the WHERE should be a.id_tag in (1,5,7,9) and HAVING sum(if(a.id_tag in(1,5,7,9),1,0))=4 (tags amount in condition =4)

Comment: The WHERE leaves us only articles which has at least one of the tags. But sum calculates for each group amount of tags of specified type.After that HAVING leaves only valid counts

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM article_has_tag a 
where a.id_tag = 1 and a.id_tag = 4
```

Returns 0 rows meaning u are using AND

```
where a.id_tag = 1 and a.id_tag = 4
```

So its looking id_tag is 1 and its 4 so it never happens. In other words you are asking to find something on a column which co-exist at the same time.

So you may need to `OR`  or `IN(1,4)`

Comment: But it returns id_article = 2 too, but I need only articles which have sql AND java

Comment: In that case u have to use `group by id_article
having count(*)=2` this will ensure that your selected data is having 2 tags associated as in the filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  id_article FROM article_has_tag a 
where a.id_tag IN (1, 10)
group by id_article
having count(*)=2
```

Where 2 - is amount of tags on which you filter your articles

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32e2a/9)

Answer (score -1):

Try with OR condition

```
SELECT * FROM article_has_tag a 
where a.id_tag = 1 or a.id_tag = 4
group by id_article
having count(id_article)=2
```

Comment: This query will return all articles with tags `sql` OR `java`